# Parse - app termination error

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, parse-platform

In my chat app while running it shows the following error with parse,

```
 Trying to retrieve from cache
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done.'
```

Whats wrong with this,please help me out?Thanks in advance

Comment: Wonder why didn't you posted the code, so that others could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(For clarity, the OP is referring to the [parse.com](http://parse.com) BaaS SDK).

You're probably trying to do something to a `PFQuery` while it's in the middle of the previous operation. Parse objects can only perform one network operation at a time. Look through your code to see whether you're making two query calls on the same query object without waiting for the first to complete.

Comment: In my case, I was defining a PFQuery object outside of a for loop and then modifying it inside the loop. This caused an issue as you explain in your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using an old version of the Parse iOS SDK. Updating to the latest version should resolve this issue.